# How to refresh a single cell in google sheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-macro

I wanted a solution for single cell refresh in google sheets.

Searched in here and got an excellent solution.

" 1. Select the cell you want updated.
2. Delete the cell.
3. Undo with Edit > Undo or Ctrl + z
This is by no means the technically savvy way to do it, but if you delete the cell, then undo, it will reload."

I tried and it works very well. Why not have a
macro with a nice short cut.

please work out and inform the community. I am sure there are amny takers fo this macro.
I am not coder and do not know @ sheet macro coding.

Comment: Welcome to [Web Applications Stack Exchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tour). Your post does not really present a question. See [How do I ask a good question?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
/**
* Clears the current cell, then restores its content.
*/
function clearAndRestore() {
  const cell = SpreadsheetApp.getCurrentCell();
  const content = cell.getFormula() || cell.getValue();
  cell.clearContent();
  SpreadsheetApp.flush();
  cell.setValue(content);
}
```